# Surveyjs - change title of question on condition

Tags: surveyjs

I am working with SurveyJS to create a survey. The answer of the first question can be either *TRUE* or *FALSE* (the user can choose by using a radio button). I would like to set the **title** of the second question depending on the answer given to the first question. In particular, the title of the second question should be *'What is your age?'* if the first question has been answered *TRUE*, *'How old are you?'* otherwise. I read a bit of the SurveyJS documentation, but I didn't find a way to do that. Do you have any suggestion? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a calculated value:

```
{
 "pages": [
  {
   "name": "page1",
   "elements": [
    {
     "type": "radiogroup",
     "name": "question1",
     "choices": [
      "item1",
      "item2"
     ]
    },
    {
     "type": "checkbox",
     "name": "question2",
     "title": "{var1}",
     "choices": [
      "item1",
      "item2",
      "item3"
     ]
    }
   ]
  }
 ],
 "calculatedValues": [
  {
   "name": "var1",
   "expression": "iif({question1} = 'item1', 'First item', 'Second item')"
  }
 ]
}
```